# How can I have python notify if an objected is deleted before the script finishes running?

Tags: python, garbage-collection

Basically I have some objects that I want to make available at global level, and I want to be notified if the user accidentally overwrites any of them, because they have very common variable names (this is necessary, and I cannot get around it).

So, for instance, if the user does `b=2`, and later the garbage collector does a sweep, I want to be notified that `b` was destroyed. However, if this happens at the end of the script, when everything else is being garbage collected, that should be silent. This is why simply implementing a `__del__` method is not good enough.

I'm delving into the `weakref` module but it doesn't seem to be what I need.

Comment: Is there a reason you WANT the user to be allowed to overwrite these objects? Or would it be preferable to lock them up while your script is running?

Comment: it would be preferable to lock them up, but their variable name is important. it's not good enough that the underlying object that was referred to as `b` is alive, `b` needs to point to that object.

Comment: also, using the variable names for other purposes within a function scope should be okay too. it's only at the global level that these variables need to be 'sacred'

Comment: Since that is preferable, I suggest clarifying that this is the goal of your question, then; or, alternatively, give a fuller description of your problem and let the answerer suggest a solution you may not have considered, rather than asking how to accomplish your assumed-best-solution.

Comment: Are you running some foreign ("user") code inside a sandboxed execution environment? You could use `exec` with a custom `dict` subclass as the globals in that case.

Comment: How about having a global variable `delNotify` which controls whether your modified `__del__` methods emit a notification or not? Set it to `False` just before you exit the program/ return from `main`, etc.

Comment: ^ this is what I was thinking. Is there any signal emitted by the python parser when it reaches the end of the file, or some name for the start of the *default* 'wrapping up' ceremony?

Comment: I suggest taking a look at the [`threading` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html). Using the [`with` statement](https://docs.python.org/release/2.5/whatsnew/pep-343.html), you should be able to lock up and release all the variables you need to protect very easily.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're executing external "untrusted" code via `exec` or `eval`, you can pass in a custom `globals` object that can tell you if something gets overwritten or deleted. You can even arrange to forbid certain kinds of modifications.

As a simple example:

```
class readonly_dict(dict):
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        raise NotImplementedError

exec "print x; x = 3" in readonly_dict(x = 10)
```

This prints 10, then throws a `NotImplementedError` when the user code tries to change `x`. You can override `__delitem__` and `__setitem__` to suit your needs.

---

As for suppressing output from `__del__` at exit: you can use the `register` function from the built-in `atexit` module to register a shutdown hook that runs before destructors, and have it set a flag that silences `__del__`.